# Excel 2010 asking for PW twice upon Open via VBA in open of another workbook

Tags: excel, passwords, subroutine, vba

I have a Workbook that, when opened, I would like to pull copied information from another workbook located on a shared drive on a remote server.  This remote file, though, is password protected. When these files are on the same computer, it works fine.  When tested over the network, though, it prompts me for the password almost as if it were a loop glitch.  That is to say, when it prompts me, even if I cancel, it will still use the password given from the code and complete.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set DATES = Workbooks.Open("Shareddrivepath\test.xlsx", password:="test")
    Range("G2:H27").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2:D27").PasteSpecial
    Range("J2:K27").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("G2:H27").PasteSpecial
    Range("A1:E21").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SET").Range("A1:E21").PasteSpecial


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

DATES.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Is there something I am missing that can load that password immediately or will it have to be linked to another sub called upon when opened?  I have also tried just merely linking the cells and it still requires/requests password on start.

Comment: I believe I found a way around this:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-and-manage-links-to-other-workbooks-HA001054812.aspx

Linking to password protected workbooks
If you want users to have to enter a password to update links, save the source workbook file with a password to open (click Save As on the File menu, click General Options on the Tools menu "Password to modify").

    Set DATES = Workbooks.Open ("Shareddrivepath\test.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="test")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found a way around this:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-and-manage-links-to-other-workbooks-HA001054812.aspx

Linking to password protected workbooks
Assigning a protection password to a source worksheet or workbook does not prevent users of linking workbooks who don't know the password from updating the links. If you want users to have to enter a password to update links, save the source workbook file with a password to open (click Save As on the File menu, click General Options on the Tools menu).

```
Set DATES = Workbooks.Open _
                    ("Shareddrivepath\test.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="test")
```

Comment: Will accept this as the correct answer in 20ish hours as long as no one else has any other ideas :)